# how to get multiple option from select input laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a simple problem  In my controller,  I want to get a multiple id of the objects with "select multiple options".How to do it?

> this is the view .now how i can receive 'vehicule[]' in methode store  of controller

```
<div class="col-md-6 form-group @if($errors->get('vehicule')) has-error @endif">
    <label for="vehicule" class="col-md-3 control-label"> Vehicule </label>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <select name="vehicule[]" id="vehicule" class="form-control" multiple="multiple" >
            @foreach ($vats as $vat)
            <option value="{{$vat->id}}"> 
                {{ $vat->matricule }} 
            </option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to put it to comment put I have lack of reputation,
But here's my answer, you can check the ID by using

```
dd($request);
```

and you can get it one by one by using

```
foreach($request->vehicule as v)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array cast in your model to store the array and bind it with form collective to edit data.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting

class User extends Model{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'options' => 'array',
    ];
}